# Android studio Importing unity project error(Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION)

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

This error is bothering me for two days. So I need to import a Project from unity into android studio but gives me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Passingdata1\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Passingdata1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/king/passingdata/BuildConfig;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

My build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.king.passingdata"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/myandroidplugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/QCARUnityPlayer.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
    compile files('libs/Vuforia.jar')
}
```

I see a lot of `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:` and `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.` here in stackoverflow and in other website, but non of them seems to be similar with my error or helpful with my situation.

Comment: What libraries are those? Do you need them all? Can you convert them to Gradle dependencies?

Comment: yes i need them all. those are the libraries from unity. I dont know how to convert them into gradle dependencies

Answer (score 1):

In your build.gradle file try adding the following block inside your android block.

```
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
}
```

And your **defaultConfig** add this

> multiDexEnabled true

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true;
    }
```

In you gradle dependency add,

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

In Application class, attachBaseContext method include this line,

> MultiDex.install(this);

```
public class ExampleApp extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml file,

> Add attribute "name" and assign above mentioned Application Class.

```
 <application
        android:name="com.ExampleApp">

<!--- Activities -->

</application>
```

Now try to run your project after clean and build your project.

Hope it will help you my dear friend !

Comment: MultiDex is never the answer. That bloats and slows down your application.

Comment: Yes. I know my friend, but if anyone stuck on that part, then android provide multidex support thing, So that we can go ahead with our Application developement. I found one link also on that. Please refer to this link. http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/building/multidex.html#dev-build . It's good practice if we remove unnecessary libraries and all stuff, but if we stuck somewhere, Android provide this thing. Hope it will help to @dens14345.

Comment: thanks for your help my friend, I followed every steps you wrote, but however I am getting this error: 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/king/passingdata/BuildConfig.class


what are these? How can i resolve these?

Comment: can you paste your gradle and manifest file here ? So that I can check what exactly the problem is.

Comment: can you provide App Gradle file? Top-level build gradle not needed here. And also paste your Application Java file.

Comment: And i observed that you didn't put any "name" attribute in <application> tag in manifest as mentioned above in my answer, Please check that.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CBKL5DTv I have two Unity class in my project: (
UnityPlayerActivity, UnityPlayerNativeActivity )

Comment: my gradle is included in my post. and I dont really get what I am going to put here :  <application
        android:name="com.ExampleApp">

<!--- Activities -->

</application>

Comment: Please add one class that extends Application. and follow my above answer. You'll get this class name where you set "name" attribute in Application tag in manifest.

Comment: thanks @Rahul , sorry I didn't saw that class that extends application, my bad, I double check it and followed every steps you wrote, but I keep getting this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/king/passingdata/BuildConfig.class

Comment: Okay @dens , Now please read carefully, I need your UPDATED app gradle file(NOT TOP LEVEL GRADLE FILE), manifest file and Application class file for checking. Please provide that.

Comment: app gradle: 
http://pastebin.com/wygrTqMK


manifest:
http://pastebin.com/3EdhZwHq

Application class file:
http://pastebin.com/evgBJcFa

thanks for helping me @Rahul

Comment: @dens please remove dexOptions from Gradle dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    } Or comment it. And let me know that you'll get success or not. Okay.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @Rahul but it still gives me the error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/king/passingdata/BuildConfig.class

Comment: @Dens , in libs folder, which libraries (jars) you included ?

Comment: compile files('libs/myandroidplugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/QCARUnityPlayer.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
    compile files('libs/Vuforia.jar')
these are the jars that i included in my project @Rahul