# Android build fails with Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: java, android, gradle, jvm, android-proguard

Error that I'm getting

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

It happens only when I try to minify the apk using Proguard. When
minifyEnabled is set to false the build is successful. It happens in both the cases of release and debug configurations with minifyEnabled set to true.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHg9W.png)

My gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.****"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 105
    versionName "1.0.5"
    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        jniDebuggable false
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}
repositories {
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':library')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:2.2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.4.4@aar'
compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

*Things i have tried*

1. Enabling multidex
2. Increase JVM heap size
3. Changing android studio vmoptions
4. Adding google play services 2.0 alpha and gradle 2.0 alpha in top level gradle
5. Clean project, make project
6. Deleting intermediates folder

Any suggestions apart from these?

Comment: this will help you my friend ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329835/android-studio-importing-unity-project-errorerrorexecution-failed-for-task-a/35331005#35331005

Comment: rebuild project then try ....one more option to try restart android studio..

Comment: <application
        android:name=".util.GlobalClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

public class GlobalClass extends Application{
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

this is the manifest and java class that I am using. Didn't get rid of the error

Comment: didn't work with invalidating caches and restart + clean project and rebuid. Still having the issue